# Memory Issue with Large Matrix Iterations

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, memory

I am working on a Jacobi/SOR problem with matrix iterations. I have a matrix of size n = 40, 80, however, I cannot get my iterations past 14 before my program slows down dramatically. Is there a way to speed this up?

````
n = 40;

(*Matrix information*)
Subscript[A, 2] = 
  Total[{DiagonalMatrix[Array[-1 &, n - 1], -1], 
    DiagonalMatrix[Array[2 &, n]], 
    DiagonalMatrix[Array[-1 &, n - 1], 1]}];
b = ConstantArray[0, n];
k = 1;
h = (1/(n + 1));
While[k < n + 1, b[[k]] = h^2 Sin[3 \[Pi] (h*k)]; k++]

L = Total[{DiagonalMatrix[Array[-1 &, n - 1], -1], 
    DiagonalMatrix[Array[0 &, n]], 
    DiagonalMatrix[Array[0 &, n - 1], 1]}];
U  =  Total[{DiagonalMatrix[Array[0 &, n - 1], -1], 
    DiagonalMatrix[Array[0 &, n]], 
    DiagonalMatrix[Array[-1 &, n - 1], 1]}];
d  =  Total[{DiagonalMatrix[Array[0 &, n - 1], -1], 
    DiagonalMatrix[Array[2 &, n]], 
    DiagonalMatrix[Array[0 &, n - 1], 1]}];
Subscript[C, J] = Dot[-Inverse[d], L + U];
No = Norm[Subscript[C, J]];

Timing[
 
 (*The Jacobi iteration loop*)
 x[0] = ConstantArray[0, n];
 x[n_] := x[n] = Dot[Subscript[C, J], x[n - 1]] + Dot[Inverse[d], b];
k = 1;


While[k < 6000, 
 Print["At k = ", k, " the approx is ", N[x[k]], ". Error is: ", 
  N[(No/(1 - No))*Norm[x[k] - x[k - 1]]]];
 If[(No/(1 - No))*Norm[x[k] - x[k - 1]] < (10)^-3, 
  Print["Success @ ", k]; Break[], k++]
 ]
 ]
```
````

Comment: You might try to save the previous step and free up the memory for the next one at each step? Some combination of `DumpSave` and `Get` would help you to only ever have the last step and current step in memory at most if formulated right. I don’t have the time to implement this, but just an idea for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what was wrong and how to fix the issue:

**Problem**:
Mathematica was storing values *symbolically*, which means it was storing functions to be evaluated that were of lengths 3000+ in a single array cell. This is unlike other programs like Python and Matlab, which do things numerically automatically. The symbolic evaluation in Mathematica is why the matrix iterations slowed down at a certain point; the concatenation of freakishly long functions to be evaluated.

**Solution**:
The solution to this is exceptionally simple, and, admittedly, I should have caught it much sooner. Instead of:

```
 (*The Jacobi iteration loop*)
 x[0] = ConstantArray[0, n];
 x[n_] := x[n] = Dot[Subscript[C, J], x[n - 1]] + Dot[Inverse[d], b];
```

It should be:

```
x[0] = ConstantArray[0, n];
 x[n_] := x[n] = N[Dot[Subscript[C, J], x[n - 1]]] + N[Dot[Inverse[d], b]];
```

Simply adding the N converts to numerical storing. With this, Mathematica is back to high speed.

**Conclusion**:
ALWAYS STORE YOUR VALUES NUMERICALLY WHEN DOING NUMERICAL METHODS!!!

Comment: Should we not establish a working precision of the computation?  That is, instead of using N[val] which uses machine precision, use val=SetPrecision[val,workingPrecision] then all numerical calculations begin with a precision of workingPrecision.  Unless ok with 16 digits of precision that is.